# Where can I get Mac OS X old SDKs?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sdk, xcode5

Latest Xcode doesn't have old sdks.
For example, Xcode 4.6.2 doesn't have "MacOSX10.6.sdk".

I know how to install sdks into Xcode.
First, in Finder, select Xcode.app, and right click to show contents of the package.
Second, go to "Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs".
You will find MacOSX10.8.sdk (if you have Xcode 4, you will also find MacOSX10.7.sdk).
You can install old SDKs to put them here.

But I can't get SDK files without installing Xcode. So, I would like to download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download them from here:
https://mega.co.nz/#!Ah0SkBaZ!KjBEcnnCmgk3ku2h2Uz3ECFxXZck36PecX-9U51NM5k

This dmg file has MacOSX10.4u.sdk ~ MacOSX10.8.sdk.